# AE Extendscript layered source file

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I'm working on a script that does find/replace for missing items in your project. Unfortunately I'm running into a situation detecting and then replacing layered image sources (psd, ai, etc.).

1) I see no way of detecting if a AvItem is a layer within a layered image other than parsing the item.name, which is unreliable because a user can always rename items in the project panel.

2) Once I do know that it is a part of a layered image I cannot figure out how to re-link it to the correct image without replacing the layer with the merged image. `item.replace(new_path)` will replace that item with the whole image, not the layer within the image. For example:

```
var item = app.project.item(3); //assuming this is the 'layer' we want to replace
item.replace(new_path);
```

So is there a secret property somewhere which will reliably tell me if an item is a part of a layered image, and if so is there a way to relink it without replacing the layer with the entire merged image?

EDIT

Here's a function to guess if a layer is part of a layered image. It's not bullet-proof but it should work as long as the user does not rename the item:

```
function isSourceLayered (av_item) {
    // check if there is a "/"
    if (av_item.name.indexOf("/") != -1) {
        // check if it is in a "layers" folder
        if (av_item.parentFolder.name.indexOf("Layers") != -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can also check the layer source and see if it can be imported as a comp. It won't tell you if it *was* imported as a layer from a comp, but like the slash in the name, it's a clue. `var io = new ImportOptions(File("c:\\myFile.psd"));
if io.canImportAs(ImportAsType.COMP) {
   <probably a comp>
}`

Answer (score 0):

I just asked the [same question](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2619536) on the Adobe extendscript forum. Unless there's undocumented features (and I spent a bit of time looking with Extendscript Toolkit's data browser) the [fileSource](http://docs.aenhancers.com/sources/filesource/) object doesn't seem to have any attributes or methods to do this.

There is a kind of a workaround, you can import the file using `ImportOptions.importAs(ImportAsType.COMP)` This will import a comp, and you can loop through the layers matching the name, get the source of that layer and use that as your new source. But as you say, it doesn't work if the source has been renamed.

<strike>I've written this into a function, it's available on [github](https://github.com/stibinator/stibsAEScripts/blob/master/(lib)/duplicate%20layer%20source.jsx)</strike> **Edit:** I forgot that I changed the way that function works. It doesn't re-import layer sources because of this problem, it just uses the **Duplicate** menu command.

Comment: Thanks stib, so I guess my fears are confirmed! I filed a feature request in the User Voice forum a while back for exposing more data to extendscript (also would love frame ranges for sequences). I checked out your function, I think I could implement something similar but it does get messy... Anyway thanks for the info!

Comment: I added a function above to attempt to detect if an item is layered if you want it.